# SQLite: How to create a combination of unrelated elements of two queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, combinations

I have one table that I need to get some metrics from.

For example I have the following table:

| meas_count | skippings | links | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 4.2 | some |
| 10 | 9 | 5.8 | some |
| 10 | 9 | 5.8 | some_2 |
| 11 | 8 | 4.2 | some |
| 11 | 8 | 5.8 | some |
| 11 | 9 | 5.9 | some |

**I need to get** a view of an existing table in the **following** form for further work:

| meas_count | skippings | links_min | links_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 0 | 4 |
| 10 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 10 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 10 | 9 | 0 | 4 |
| 10 | 9 | 4 | 5 |
| 10 | 9 | 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 8 | 0 | 4 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 11 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 9 | 0 | 4 |
| 11 | 9 | 4 | 5 |
| 11 | 9 | 5 | 6 |

At the moment I have 2 queries, the results of which I need to combine to get the result I need.

First request:

```sql
SELECT meas_count,skippings FROM current_stats GROUP BY meas_count,skippings
```

Creates the following:

| meas_count | skippings |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 8 |
| 11 | 9 |

Second request:

```sql
SELECT 
LAG(rounded) OVER (ORDER BY rounded) as links_min, 
rounded as links_max FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ROUND(links, 1) as rounded FROM current_stats) 
GROUP BY rounded ORDER BY rounded)
```

Creates the following:

| links_min | links_max |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

I need something like result of sets multiplication...

**What query should be executed to get the table of the view I need as a result?**

I also have an **additional question**: *is the execution of the second query slowed down due to several SELECTs inside?*

Comment: You can do that by doing an `INNER JOIN` on the two tables without specifying a join condition.  That will give you every combination of the two sets of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by doing an `INNER JOIN` on the two tables without specifying a join condition.  That will give you every combination of the two sets of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT meas_count,skippings
    FROM current_stats
    GROUP BY meas_count,skippings)
AS one
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LAG(rounded) OVER (ORDER BY rounded) as links_min, 
 rounded as links_max FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT ROUND(links, 1) as rounded FROM current_stats) 
     GROUP BY rounded
     ORDER BY rounded  
    )
) AS two;
```

As for performance, that's really only an issue if there is a better way to do it.  Of course nested SELECTs take time, but the query optimizers in today's SQL engine are pretty good at determining what you MEANT from what you SAID.

Comment: In my case, I can write a second query with only one SELECT: `SELECT LAG(ROUND(links, 1)) OVER (ORDER BY ROUND(links, 1)) as links_min, ROUND(links, 1) as links_max FROM current_stats GROUP BY ROUND(links, 1) ORDER BY ROUND(links, 1)`. So will it be better or worse? Theoretically, as far as I understand, the optimizer can understand that ROUND can be executed only once. Then this option will be faster than the similar one with the SELECTs? The multiple SELECT option seems more difficult to optimize.

Comment: Unless you have millions of records, it won't matter.  Beware of premature optimization.

Comment: I do have a lot of records... Not millions, but about a million...